# Ajax not making changes

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm working through a book on PHP and jQuery and I've encountered a problem with Ajax, in that it will not post it's changes and display them.

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Testing jQuery</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p class="foo">Another paragraph, but this one ahs a class.</p>
    <p><span>This is a span in a paragraph</span></p>
    <p id="bar">Paragraph with an id.
        <span class="foo">And this is a sentence in a span</span>
    </p>
    <script src="jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery/ajax.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>

    <form action="#" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Sign Up Form</legend>
            <label for="name">Name</label><br/>
            <input name="name" id="name" type="text" /><br/>
            <label for="password">Password</label><br/>
            <input name="password" id="password"
                   type="password" /><br/>
            <label>
                <input id="mycomp" type="radio" name="loc" />
                I'm on my computer.
            </label><br/>
            <label>
                <input id="shared" type="radio" name="loc" checked="checked" />
                I'm on my shared computer.
            </label>
            <input type="submit" value="Log In" /><br/>
            <label>
                <input id="signedin" type="checkbox" name="notify"
                       disabled="true"/>
                Keep me signed in on this computer.
            </label><br/>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code for the test site. It's exceedingly simple yet this ajax query won't modify it:

```
    $.ajax({
  "type":"POST",
  "url":"ajax.php",
  "data":"var1=val1&var2=val2",
  "success":function(data){
    $("#bar")
    .css("background","yellow")
    .html(data);
  }
});
```

I'm running it through the firebug console, and it seems to be functioning correctly, but nothing is actually happening.

Comment: Nothing I can see would cause the success function to not update the #bar element. Are you sure the call is succeeding? Try adding an "error" function to see if that gets called instead.

Comment: Define "nothing is happening".  You say you're using Firebug to debug this?  When you step through each executing line of code, where does it fail?  Is the expected network request made?  What is the server's response?  Does the jQuery selector find the element you expect it to?  etc.

Comment: what is in your php file? have you return anything from there

Comment: It's not throwing an error, and I'm at a loss for why it wouldn't modify it.

Comment: AJAX calls should not throw an error when failing. Follow @Tyler's suggestion.

Comment: This is the info stored in the ajax file: <?php

echo '<p class="ajax">This paragraph was loaded with AJAX.</p>',
'<pre>GET variables: ', print_r($_GET, TRUE), '</pre>' ,
'<pre>POST variables: ', print_r($_POST, TRUE), '</pre>';

?>

Comment: [This is what the screen looks like after running it.](http://imgur.com/Vet1oH4)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I try to explain all.
First, when you want send a form with ajax, you don't use submit and attributes of tag . You assign function to button or element to submit the form, and this function do the call ajax, for example.

With your html, this Jquery code:

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(submitForm);
function submitForm(){
$.ajax({
   "type":"POST",
   "url":"ajax.php",
   "data":"var1=val1&var2=val2",
   "success":function(data){
       $("#bar")
       .css("background","yellow")
       .html(data);
   }
 });
}
```

And if you do POST, you must send a variables in array or like this:

```
"data": {
   var1:val1,
   var2:val2
 }
```

You receive in $_POST[var1] and $_POST[var2] in ajax.php.

So your javascript/Jquery code would be something like this:

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(submitForm);
function submitForm(){
$.ajax({
  "type":"POST",
  "url":"ajax.php",
  "data": {
       var1:val1,
       var2:val2
     },
  "success":function(data){
    $("#bar")
    .css("background","yellow")
    .html(data);
  }
});
}
```

If you have any question, tell me. I hope this be useful for you.

Comment: AJAX Post data can be made with query strings, it doesn't need to be an object.

Comment: True, but send a string its like GET petition. I think